# How do I fix a gap in text in inDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, cs6

I have text that flows from page to page and all of the pages look good - except one! In the middle of the paragraph there is about a 2 inch gap before the next line of text shows. As far as I can see the paragraph style is the same as all the other paragraphs. I don't know what to do.

Could anyone help in fixing this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try:

- Is there an item with text wrap on the page?
- Do you have some kind of "Keep with Next" setting checked?
- If you copy this text to a brand new document, does it do the same
  thing? (Then you have a Page Return character somewhere.)

If all else fails, copy this chunk of text to a text file (NOT Word or the like) to strip out formatting, copy it back to the document, and restyle it.

If even that fails, delete the page, put in a new one, and try re-placing the text frame.

If even THAT fails, you may have prefs issues with your ID document and you may have to recreate it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance on this, Lauren. Your second solution was the answer to my problem. I had to uncheck the "Keep with Previous" box.

Comment: Those are sneaky. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that there is a column or page break character at the end of the text on page 147 that you provided. A quick way to check is to select the menu TYPE > SHOW HIDDEN CHARACTERS.

This will show all of your spaces, hard and soft returns, and break characters.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kurtis. Although the solution did not solve this problem, it did help with a couple of others.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an object in a hidden layer that had text wrap on it. Because the layer was hidden, I couldn't see why the 2-inch gap existed. I discovered there had to be something on that page because I created a new text box, threaded the text through that new box on the page, and the gap was still there. Turned on the layer and BAM! There was my reason for the gap in the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem – thanks to Lauren's 2nd tip, I:

1. selected the T type tool
2. selected all the text in my document
3. selected my Keep options (alt-cmd-K)
4. deselected 'Keep with Previous'
5. selected 'Keep with Next 0 lines'
6. deselected 'Keep Lines Together'
7. clicked on 'OK' and:
8. Le Voila! – My unexpected gap in the text was gone and the text flowed smoothly from page to page, so:
9. I saved it!